# CAKEPHP - Including view into another view

Tags: cakephp

I have a controller for posts and an element for comments. I want to include the posts view somehow in comment element. Is this possible to include the PostsController view into an element?

I know how to include elements but never heard or thought of including Controller views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the *data* for the PostsController view using [requestAction](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arequestAction). If you want to include view-layer code in two different places, pull it into an element - that's what they're for.